Magnetic moment and pairing of electrons in hexaaquairon(III)
I understand that $\ce{H2O}$ acts as a strong ligand for $\ce{Fe^3+},$ $\ce{Cr^3+},$ and $\ce{Co^3+}.$ So, shouldn’t the electrons pair up in the $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ orbitals? Wouldn’t that cause a magnetic moment of $\sqrt{3}~\mu_\mathrm B$ and not $\sqrt{35}~\mu_\mathrm B?$

Magnetic moment is vary with number of unpaired electrons. The three ions you have mentioned have different valence electrons, 5, 3, and 6, respectively.  The ligand split the crystal field differently according to thir strength to high or low spin situations so their magnetic moments differ. See here for details.

"It is my understanding that $\ce{H2O}$ acts as a strong ligand for $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ (along with $\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ and $\ce{Co^{3+}}$)"
Whoever told you this is talking through their hat. Only with $\ce{Co^{3+}}$ is water a strong field ligand in an octahedral complex.
The central ions actually represent three different cases.
$\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ has no strong or weak field ligand effects in any octahedral complex (with simple sigma-donor ligands like water) because there are only three valence $d$ electrons; not enough to pair any of them in the lower-energy $t_{2g}$ group regardless of the ligand.
That leaves $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ and $\ce{Co^{3+}}$. If you look only at the $Dq$ value for from the crystal field $d$-orbital splitting it seems that the balance between pairing the electrons in the lower-energy group and diatributing them unpaired among all $d$ orbitals seems to be the same. But there are two subtle differences between these central ions:

The energy differential associated with allowing all electrons to remain unpaired is a quadratic function of the number of electrons that are unpaired, not a linear one. So it costs more energy to pair electrons when you have more unpaired electrons to start with; and $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ has five versus $\ce{Co^{3+}}$ having four.

The $\ce{Co^{3+}}$ ion is more compact than $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$, so the $Dq$ energy differential that favors pairing is greater in the former.


The combination of these two factors is enough for water to behave differently with the two central ions: it is not powerful enough to force $d$-electron pairing with $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$, whose complex then has all five $3d$ electrons unpaired; but water ligands can force electron pairing with the more amenable $\ce{Co^{3+}}$.

so what i learned was that for Fe+3 and Co+3 the ligands (ox) (H20) and (NH3) will act as strong field ligands. Is this not true? i don't really need a detailed explanation since the level I require for my exams is fairly low so could you just let me if this is true or false and if true for which cases(in 3d)

Whether a ligand gives a strong or a weak field can depend in the central ion, for the reasons I outline. The favorable $d^5$ configuration when irin(III) is high-spin makes the high-spin, weak-field configuration favorable specifically for that ion center and similarly for the isoelectronic manganese(II).

$H_2O$ being a Oxygen donor is a weak field ligand for $Fe^{+3}$.
Oxygen donors are generally Weak field ligands {WFL} for metals in 3d series(due to their low $Z_{eff}$), but they act as Strong field ligand {SFL} for metals having higher or Equal $Z_{eff}$ then $Co^{+3}$ (for $+3$ ions of $3d$ series) or $Cu^{+2}$ (for $+2$ ions of $3d$ series). Since $Fe^{+3}$ have less $Z_{eff}$ then $Co^{+3}$ so $H_2O$ will be a WFL for $Fe^{+3}$.
And hence there would be 5 unpaired electron in $Fe^{+3}$ and so theoretically it's magnetic moment would be $\pu{\sqrt{35} BM}$.

Extra information:
Due to dimerization in aqueous medium (as shown) Magnetic moment of $Fe^{+3}$ reduces below $\pu{\sqrt{35} BM}$.


Reference:
Chemistry of elements, 2nd ed, GreenWood and Earnshaw, pg: 1089
